# Hide closest class/link tag

Tags: jquery

When I click cancel button I want to hide the closest ".my-file" class. I am trying this:

```
<div>
    <label for="file">file</label>
    <input type="file">
    <a href="#" class="my-file">first file</a>
    <button class="cancel-button" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="file">file</label>
    <input type="file">
    <a href="#" class="my-file">Second file</a>
    <button class="cancel-button" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.cancel-button').on('click', function () {
        alert('works');
        $(this).closest('.my-file').hide();
        $(this).closest('a').hide();
    })
})
```

When I click on cancel button I get the alert, but hiding is not working. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest()` is used to find parent elements. `.my-file` is a sibling of `.cancel-button`, so you should use `siblings()` instead.

```
$('.cancel-button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.my-file').hide();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9puynax6/)

If you can guarantee that `.my-file` will always appear directly before the `.cancel-button` in your HTML, the you could use the `prev()` method instead:

```
$(this).prev().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` is used to find parent elements up the hierarchy, instead use `prev()` as shown :-

```
$(function() {
    $('.cancel-button').on('click', function () {
      $(this).prev('a.my-file').hide();//OR $(this).prev().hide();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/9puynax6/1/)